# DataTable DragDropEvent not called

Tags: drag-and-drop, primefaces

Im on PF 3.2 in Liferay  6.1 and trying to implement the Drag&Drop DataTable from the showcase. I downloaded the original code and Im using it.

The behaviour is that when I drag an item and drop into the "Selected Cars" zone, the draggable arrows icon dissapears and is not draggable anymore, but the event onCarDrop is NEVER called, so, the data is not going to the correct places. No errors in logs.

So, any idea?

The method that is never called:

```
public void onCarDrop(DragDropEvent ddEvent) {
    Car car = ((Car) ddEvent.getData());

    droppedCars.add(car);
    carsSmall.remove(car);
}
```

here is where is invoked:

```
<p:droppable for="selectedCars" tolerance="touch" activeStyleClass="ui-state-highlight" datasource="availableCars" onDrop="handleDrop">
                <p:ajax listener="#{tableBean.onCarDrop}" update="dropArea availableCars" />
</p:droppable>
```

Thx in advance.

Comment: Using the same .xhtml and Bean outside Liferay and works, the difference is the DragDropEvent, that is never called inside the portlet.

Suggestions?